# Construct a plane embedding of a given $3$-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

I`m struggling to understand a proof about general games which has single use path, and traversal location.

My problem is that I can't understand what the authors says about "Construct a
plane embedding of a given 3-regular graph G (perhaps an orthogonal embedding,
if needed) with an additional vertex u dangling from a distinguished vertex v."

A just can`t image what sort of graph would be that. Can anyone help me to understand it ?

The article is in the link below and the paragraph of this statement starts at the very end of page 3.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4995v5.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could have helped a lot here by including a simple image, but consider the [3-regular graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicGraph.html) - for example a cube. A plane embedding of a cube is quite easy to imagine as two concentric squares with the corners joined by lines.

The 'distinguished vertex' is just any vertex, but lets say one of the ones on the outer face. Then there is an edge from v to u : a 'dangling' edge, in other words.